# Redirect not working correctly but showing in logs that it was successful

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I am creating a jsfiddle clone for a class project using ruby on rails and javascript. When a user saves their project or "fiddle" I want the project to be created and then for the user to be redirected to the project's edit page. At the moment the project is saving and the logs show that the redirect was successful. The project is saving to the database but the page is not redirecting.

When a user saves a project this ajax call is made which saves the project to the database

```
function saveProject(e){
  var html = htmlEditor.getValue();
  var js = javascriptEditor.getValue();
  var css = cssEditor.getValue();
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "/projects",
     data: { project: { name: "Project", html: html, javascript: js, css:css } }
   });

 e.preventDefault();
}
```

That ajax call is connect to a create method in the ProjectsController which looks like this:

```
def create
  if user_signed_in?
    @project = Project.create(project_params)
    @project.user_id = current_user.id
  else
    @project = Project.create(project_params)
    @project.user_id = 0
   end

 redirect_to edit_project_path(@project)

end
```

As I said before, the redirect does not work but the logs show that it was successful. I screen shotted the server logs and uploaded them here

http://imgur.com/geuxdiX

I am also using the devise gem which is where the user_signed_in? check is coming from. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think because you're using AJAX, you'll need to use javascript to redirect following success.

Comment: If you look in your javascript console, you'll probably find that the response from the ajax request *is* the redirected page.   To get the redirect to work the way you want, you either need to not use `ajax` for the post, or add `success` and `error` handlers on your `ajax` call and handle the redirect there based on the state of the response.

Comment: You're using Ajax on the client side. You'll need to redirect with JavaScript when the Ajax request is done. In jQuery: `$.ajax(...).done(function(data) {window.location.replace(data.location)});` On server side in ruby, you'll need to provide JSON response like `{"location": "/projects/123/edit"}`

Comment: Thanks for the responses! I ended up replacing the redirect with render `:js => "window.location = '#{edit_project_path(@project)}'"` and it worked!